# How to conditional format a range of cells with a trigger word in one cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

All of the common answers to this question do not quite cover what I am asking.

I would like to have a row at the top of my spreadsheet where in one cell (eg. A3, B3, C3 etc..) so I can type something like 'Week 1' which will then highlight/fill the colour of the column below that - So I would like to type 'Week 1' in cell B3, which then triggers a colour change in cells B4:B12, regardless of the value in those cells for example.

The trigger has to be me typing something like 'Week 1' or 'Week 2' in a particular column to then highlight the range in that same column.

Comment: Use conditional formatting with the format based on a formula where you specify if cell B1="week 1" then highlight.

Comment: Would you type week 1 in column 1 and so on? Cause to me it seems you might want a rule to apply on all columns at once. But for that you might need some sort of rule to capture through formula.

Answer (score 0):

1. select target range: B4:B12
2. add new rule
3. choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. the formula shall be `=B3="Week 1"`
5. Define the format
6. `OK` everything until all dialog windows are closed

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the whole range (in our example A4:A10)
2. Go to Home - Styles tab - Conditional formatting - New Rule - Format only cells that contain
3. Change Cell Value to Specific Text
4. Next to containing write "Week1"
5. Press Format - Fill and select color - Press OK

**Rule:**

[image]

**Results:**

[image]